# Views not expanding to match the constraints given

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios-autolayout

I am learning UIAutolayout. In this I have learnt how to add views to the superview and then provide the constraints. I am planning to have two views on the screen, give them red and blue colours.As the constraitns are affecting both the superview and the subview (as shown in the format string) I have added the constraints to the superview.(Is this wrong???) I have typed the following code in my viewDidLoad function.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


UIView * view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] ] ;


UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view2 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]] ;


//Adding the view to the main view.
[self.view addSubview:view1] ;

[self.view addSubview:view2] ;


[view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[view2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

//Making the namemap for sending to the function
NSDictionary *nameMap = @{@"view1":view1,@"view2":view2} ;


//Creating the constraint below

NSArray * horizontalContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-30-[view2]-60-[view1]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:nameMap] ;

NSArray *view1Height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[view1]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:nameMap] ;

NSArray *view2Height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[view2]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:nameMap] ;


//Adding the constraints
[self.view addConstraints:horizontalContraints] ;

[self.view addConstraints:view2Height] ;

[self.view addConstraints:view1Height] ;
```

PROBLEM: I am getting only the blue View as the output on the screen. I am not getting the red one.I have tested this on both iPad and iPhone simulators,but results are the same. There is no more code to give. I am using Xcode 5 and iOS 7 (well, because I am learning). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your "horizontalContraints". As paresh said you need to specify the width of the views.

So, changing your "horizontalContraints" to

```
NSArray *horizontalContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-30-[view2]-60-[view1(==view2)]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict];
```

will give you the desired output.

Your whole after the change is as follows.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView * view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    [view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [view2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    //Adding the view to the main view.
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];

    NSDictionary *dict =[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dict = @{@"view1":view1, @"view2":view2};

    NSArray *horizontalContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-30-[view2]-60-[view1(==view2)]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict];

    NSArray *view1Height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[view1]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict];

    NSArray *view2Height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[view2]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict];

    [self.view addConstraints:horizontalContraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:view2Height];
    [self.view addConstraints:view1Height];
}
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

My previous answer assumed that there were no horizontal constraints on `view1` and `view2` to separate them apart (but it turns out they were in place).

The actual problem here is that when you add the `horizontalConstraints`, this is what you are telling autolayout to do:

Start from left leave a space of 30, add `view2`, then leave a space of 60, after which add `view1` and finally leave a space of 30 from right margin.

But there is nothing in here which is telling autolayout how wide it needs to keep the views (`view1` and `view2`). Even when you created your views, you did not set any frame for it (which means no height or width).

Now when your views are laid out according to these constraints, autolayout just gives the total available width to the first view in your `horizontalConstraints`, which is `view2` in your case (because no one has told autolayout to keep any width for `view1`, it is happy to set it to zero). Hence you never see your `view1`.

There are a few things you can do to fix it:

- Either set a fixed width for both views
- Set fixed width for one of the views and then the remaining width will be given to second view by autolayout.
- If you want to keep both the views equally wide then add an equal width constraint for them. Then autolayout will divide the available width equally among `view1` and `view2`.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

The problem is really simple. You are adding 2 sets of constraints, `view1Height` and `view2Height` to your `self.view`.

If you look at them closely this is what you are telling autolayout to do:

For view1:
Start from top in `self.view` leave a space of 30, then add `view1` and again leave a space of 30.

Similarly for view2: Start from top in `self.view` leave a space of 30, then add `view2` and again leave a space of 30.

So in effect you are placing both the views at exactly the same place. Hence now only z-coordinate will determine which view will be visible. Since you added view2 (the blue one) after you added view1, hence its overlapping view1. This results in.... you guessed it right, just view2 being visible.

Comment: You are right. But I also added horizontal constraints to the views, which will determine the position of the views in horizontal direction(x-direction). I have asked view2 left edge to be 30 points away from the container , its right edge to be 60 points away from view1 , view1 right edge to be 30 points away from right edge of the container. And then I have added this constraint to the superview i.e self.view. this statement.

NSArray * horizontalContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-30-[view2]-60-[view1]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:nameMap] ;

Comment: Sorry my bad I didn't notice the horizontal constraints that you added, but I found the problem. I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well like you sad you are learning, so i give you that tutorial: [AutoLayout Objective-C](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

If this not answer your question feel free to ask me :D

Comment: Thanks for asnwering. I am already using a famous book "big Nerd ranch guide-iOS programming" for it. According to the book I am doing it right , but still not getting the required results. :(